# SELinux blocks tomcat web application to load Java native library (JNI) from /tmp folder

Tags: linux, centos, security, selinux, tomcat

I have a Centos 7 with Tomcat installed and **tomcat** user

```
ls -l /var/lib/tomcat
total 0
drwxrwxrwx. 5 root tomcat 84 Jul  3 13:18 webapps
```

SELinux is enforcing and a Java web application which tries to load Java native library (JNI) from shared object files .so in /tmp/ folder cannot work.

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/app/gdal_java/2018.07.03.14.52.59/libosrjni.so: 
/tmp/app/gdal_java/2018.07.03.14.52.59/libosrjni.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied
```

If I disable SELinux, there is no problem to load these files in the Java web application. The permission of this file is:

```
ls -lZ /tmp/app/gdal_java/2018.07.03.14.52.59/libosrjni.so
-rwxrwxrwx. tomcat tomcat system_u:object_r:tomcat_tmp_t:s0 /tmp/app/gdal_java/2018.07.03.14.52.59/libosrjni.so
```

How can I configure SELinux to allow **tomcat** user to load these files from */tmp/app/* folder?

I have tried with this command and restart tomcat but it still has same error

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t tomcat_tmp_t '/tmp/app_*/(.*)?'
```

Comment: Did you run this after? - `restorecon -rv /tmp`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to run `restorecon` after defining the fcontext:

```
$ semanage fcontext -a -t tomcat_tmp_t "/tmp/app_*(/.*)?"
$ restorecon -rv /tmp
```

#### References

- https://noobient.com/post/165972214381/selinux-woes-with-tomcat-on-centos-74

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work.
sudo restorecon -rv /tmp/app/
restorecon:  Warning no default label for /tmp/app

Comment: @BằngRikimaru - this CentOS 7?

Comment: yes, and the /tmp/app already has the permission with 'system_u:object_r:tomcat_tmp_t'

Comment: @BằngRikimaru - which tomcat 7 or 8?

Comment: It is tomcat7 and user created 'tomcat' from tomcat.noarch package

Answer (score -1):

I use audit2allow tool to allow tomcat can have multiple permission (read, execute) on this /tmp/app folder.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-fixing_problems-allowing_access_audit2allow

```
cat /var/log/audit/audit.log  | audit2allow -a
```